# Sharing cookie between two asp.net mvc applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, single-sign-on, orchardcms

I have following problem: I did research about sharing cookie between two applications on a same domain but I'm pretty sure I'm missing something and didn't found my answer yet.

I have two apps on webistes like this: app.domain.com and portal.app.domain.com
First application is Orchard cms, I created my own custom membership provider so authentication in orchard looks like this:

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid && CustomMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(userNameOrEmail, password))
 {
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userNameOrEmail, true);
 }
```

and web.config in both apps.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="loginCookie" path="/" loginUrl="~/Users/Account/AccessDenied" timeout="2880" cookieless="UseCookies"
         enableCrossAppRedirects ="true" domain=".domain.com"
         requireSSL="false"/>
    </authentication>

<machineKey validationKey="CB6DEDC99140ABCEA1CFE08BEF8407BE2AE60DDB905264F6F7FAA9650B5AB4F1986F84878B4842FB9B51EDD477FFC518C6B6F1687FF25D5BAE883C313F05A6A4" decryptionKey="B0F735974F5261E63D07F4571FB11B392477173098F71E7CA76C1DD9A459C638" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

Second app is asp.net mvc 4 application.

Cookie is created every time so it works but portal.app.domain.com doesn't "see" loginCookie. Request.IsAuthenticated returns false and Request.Count doesn't contain valid number of cookies that I want. What's more when I sign on in portal.app.domain.com loginCookie is created in the exact same way but with new value. What is weird in I can fiddler see all cookies for domain. I found something about redirecting but can somone explain to me something more about it(what should I add? ), furthermore is it possibility to share cookie without redirect, I mean when sign on in app.domain.com user can write address portal.app.domain.com in browser and he can be logged in anyway?

Thank you in advance for all replies.

Comment: did you get it resolved? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong there will be a default connection string by default in each of your project
It will be as `connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"`

You will find it in `web.config` as coding take in my project i have

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Set the DefaultConnection's connection string common in both your projects so that you can have the same being set for both of your projects